# custom powershell DSC resources with composite keys

Tags: powershell, dsc

I have two entities for the sake of argument lets call them entity a and entity b, there can be a 1:M relationship between the two. What I want to do is to create a powershell dsc resource that links the two together, so that I can perform:

```
MyResource link
{
    EntityA = "entity a"
    EntityB = "entity b"
    Ensure  = "Present"
}
```

Two questions:

1. Is it possible for the [DscProperty(Key)] to be a composite of two values ?
2. Is there a more elegant solution to this problem via DSC

Answer (score 1):

It appears that in the case of a key that consists of more than one attribute, each attribute requires its own dsc property, for example, for a resource with a key composed of KeyPart1 and KeyPart2, this looks like:

```
[DscProperty(Key)]
[string]$KeyPart1
<#
    Specifies the volume to be added to / removed from the pod.
#>
[DscProperty(Key)]
[string]$KeyPart2
```